# Sorting Eigensystem According to Complicated Rule

Tags: sorting, eigenvalues

I have looked for an answer to this but the near duplicates I could find seemed slightly distinct.

I have a matrix $A$ which has eigenvalues in pairs $\lambda_1,-\lambda_1,\lambda_2,-\lambda_2,\dots$. I would like to sort the eigensystem such that the eigenvectors are in this order, with the eigenvalues having descending real parts. That is, I want to sort in descending order of the function $f=|\Re(\cdot)|$ and break ties by $g=\Re(\cdot)$.

What I was hoping for was something like:

```
f[z_] := Abs[Re[z]];
g[z_] := Re[z];
{eval,evec} = SortBy[Eigensystem[N[A]]\[Transpose],{f,z}]\[Transpose];
```

but this doesn't work. Replacing {f,g} with Abs@*Re does work but not for the tiebreak (neither does {Abs@*Re,Re}).

An example matrix that is $8\times 8$ is the following (although any anti-symmetric matrix has plus/minus pairs of eigenvalues):

```
A = {{0, 0, -1, -4*I, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -4*I, 
      0, 0}, {4*I, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -4*I}, {0, 0, 4*I, 1, 0, 0, 
      0, -1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {0, 0, 0, 0, 4*I, 1, 0, 0}}
```

Edit:
Additionally, I have realised since writing this that for my application I probably want to organise the sorting differently than I've asked for. In particular I want to order first by `f[z_] :=Abs[Re[z]]`, then break ties first by `g[z_]:=Re[z]*Im[z]` and second by `h[z_]:=Re[z]`. So a solution that enables me to simply list three functions f,g,h which I've defined elsewhere in my code would be preferable.

Comment: What is your `A`?

Comment: A is some matrix defined elsewhere in my code. A typical small example would be```A = {{0,0,1,-I},{0,0,0,1},{-1,0,0,0},{I,-1,0,0}}```.

Answer (score 2):

**New Edition**

```
A = {{0, 0, 1, -I}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {I, -1, 0, 0}};
result = Rule @@ Reverse@(A // N // Eigensystem) // Thread // 
  Association
SortBy[result, Re, Abs[#1] > Abs[#2] &]
```

**Old Editon**

We need a large `A` to test the code.

```
A = {{0, 0, 1, -I}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 0, 0}, {I, -1, 0, 0}};
result = Rule @@ Reverse@(A // N // Eigensystem) // Thread // 
  Association
ReverseSortBy[result, {Abs@*Re[#] &, Re[#] &}]
```

**Original**

What is your `A`?

use `Association` can keep the tie. Since we don't know `A`,here we set

```
eval=A//N//Eigensystem//First;
evac=A//N//Eigensystem//Last;
```

```
eval = {1 + 3 I, -(1 + 3 I), 2 - I, -(2 - I), 5 + I, -(5 + I), 
   3 - 8 I, -(3 - 8 I), 0.1 - 8 I, -(0.1 - 8 I)};
evac = Array[v, Length@eval];
result = ReverseSortBy[
  Association[Thread[evac -> eval]], {Abs[Re[#]] &, Re[#] &}]
{neweval, newevec} = {Values[result], Keys[result]};
```

```
<|v[5] -> 5 + I, v[6] -> -5 - I, v[7] -> 3 - 8 I, v[8] -> -3 + 8 I, 
 v[3] -> 2 - I, v[4] -> -2 + I, v[1] -> 1 + 3 I, v[2] -> -1 - 3 I, 
 v[9] -> 0.1 - 8. I, v[10] -> -0.1 + 8. I|>

{{5 + I, -5 - I, 3 - 8 I, -3 + 8 I, 2 - I, -2 + I, 1 + 3 I, -1 - 3 I, 
  0.1 - 8. I, -0.1 + 8. I}, {v[5], v[6], v[7], v[8], v[3], v[4], v[1],
   v[2], v[9], v[10]}}
```

Comment: `ReverseSortBy[Eigensystem[N[A]] // Transpose, {Abs[Re[#]], Re[#]} &] // Transpose` should be enough

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting the first solution to work at all. The original solution seems to sort in the opposite order to the one I want - that is, for an example 4x4 matrix I might get real parts in the order (-3.7 , +3.7, -0.27, +0.27) whilst I want (+3.7,-3.7+0.27,-0.27).

Comment: @Roman does that differ substantially than what I put in the OP? I can't get that to work either.

Comment: @jacob1729 you can edit you original question and add a 10*10 matrix  so that we can easy to test the method.

Comment: @cvgmt I have realised that the order I specified in the OP is not correct for my application and that I actually want order according to different functions - should I open a new question or is it easy to adapt this to ordering first by some function $f(z)$ and tie-break on a different function $g(z)$ where $f,g$ are not Mathematica built-ins like Re and Abs?

Comment: @cvgmt ah I see that this does work but only if I round the output of Eigensystem.